# Cauchy's two-line notation in LaTeX when columns extend outside horizontal box

Tags: matrices

I need help with writing a permutation in Cauchy's two-line notation that has many columns please. Because there are so many columns, it extends outside the horizontal box. I have decided that the best thing to do is to split it over two lines.

Below is a MWE. The first produces the notation exactly how I would like it if it didn't extend outside the horizontal box. The second is an attempt to split it over two lines so it is within the horizontal box. I am more or less happy with the second one, except for how it treats the parentheses. I want the left parenthesis to take the first two lines and the right parenthesis to take the last two lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\sigma=\left(\begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \ldots{} & \frac{n}{2}-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+1 & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots{} & n-3 & n-2 & n-1 & n  \\
1 & \frac{n}{2}+1 & 3 & \frac{n}{2}+3 & \ldots{} & \frac{n}{2}-1 & n-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots{} & 4 & n-2 & 2 & n  \\
\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\multirow{2}{*}{$\sigma=($} & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & \ldots{} & $\frac{n}{2}-1$ & $\frac{n}{2}$ & \\
 & $1$ & $\frac{n}{2}+1$ & $3$ & $\frac{n}{2}+3$ & \ldots{} & $\frac{n}{2}-1$ & $n-1$ & \\
 & $\frac{n}{2}+1$ & $\frac{n}{2}+2$ & \ldots{} & $n-3$ & $n-2$ & $n-1$ & $n$ & \multirow{2}{*}{)} \\
 & $\frac{n}{2}$ & $\frac{n}{2}+2$ & \ldots{} & $4$ & $n-2$ & $2$ & $n$ & \\
\end{tabular}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Cauchy's two-line notation is essentially just a matrix with two rows, so a solution using matrices would be fine too. Any other suggestions to make the notation take less space are welcome too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\sigma=\left(\begin{array}{@{}*{20}{c@{}}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \ldots{} & \frac{n}{2}-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+1 & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots{} & n-3 & n-2 & n-1 & n  \\
1 & \frac{n}{2}+1 & 3 & \frac{n}{2}+3 & \ldots{} & \frac{n}{2}-1 & n-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots{} & 4 & n-2 & 2 & n  \\
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation*}
or
\begin{equation*}
\sigma=\left(\begin{array}{@{}*{20}{c@{\,}}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \ldots{} & \frac{n}{2}-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+1 & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots{} & n-3 & n-2 & n-1 & n  \\
1 & \frac{n}{2}+1 & 3 & \frac{n}{2}+3 & \ldots{} & \frac{n}{2}-1 & n-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots{} & 4 & n-2 & 2 & n  \\
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also just set the `\arraycolsep` to whatever value you like.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0.5pt}
\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \ldots{} & \frac{n}{2}-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+1 & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots{} & n-3 & n-2 & n-1 & n  \\
1 & \frac{n}{2}+1 & 3 & \frac{n}{2}+3 & \ldots{} & \frac{n}{2}-1 & n-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots{} & 4 & n-2 & 2 & n  \\
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

You may want to make these changes local.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\newenvironment{CauchyArray}[1][1pt]{\begingroup\setlength{\arraycolsep}{#1}\begin{pmatrix}}
{\end{pmatrix}\endgroup}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\sigma=\begin{CauchyArray}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \ldots{} & \frac{n}{2}-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+1 & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots{} & n-3 & n-2 & n-1 & n  \\
1 & \frac{n}{2}+1 & 3 & \frac{n}{2}+3 & \ldots{} & \frac{n}{2}-1 & n-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots{} & 4 & n-2 & 2 & n  \\
\end{CauchyArray}.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\sigma=\begin{CauchyArray}[1.5pt]
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \ldots{} & \frac{n}{2}-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+1 & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots{} & n-3 & n-2 & n-1 & n  \\
1 & \frac{n}{2}+1 & 3 & \frac{n}{2}+3 & \ldots{} & \frac{n}{2}-1 & n-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots{} & 4 & n-2 & 2 & n  \\
\end{CauchyArray}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but there isn't enough horizontal spacing for my liking. Is there a way of maximizing the horizontal spacing without going outside the page limits?

Comment: @JonathanMitchell In principle, yes, but then the gaps will look different in each scheme. I added a version with a bit more space.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That seems to work quite well if I introduce a bit more space and change the fractions. Here's what I did.

`\begin{equation*}
\sigma=\left(\begin{array}{@{}*{20}{c@{\,\,\,}}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \ldots{} & \frac{n-2}{2} & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n+2}{2} & \frac{n+4}{2} & \ldots{} & n-3 & n-2 & n-1 & n  \\
1 & \frac{n+2}{2} & 3 & \frac{n+6}{2} & \ldots{} & \frac{n-2}{2} & n-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n+2}{2} & \ldots{} & 4 & n-2 & 2 & n  \\
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation*}`

Comment: @JonathanMitchell You can also play with `\arraycolsep`. Maybe this is the cleaner option.

Comment: That's a bit better. It gives me a bit more flexibility. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `array` contains 14 columns and hence 13 intercolumn spaces. To make your `array` (or `pmatrix`) environment fit inside the text block, you have two main, not mutually exclusive, options:

- reduce the value of the `\arraycolsep` parameter (default value: 5pt), which governs the amount of intercolumn whitespace. (This is the approach taken in the [earlier answer of @Schrödinger'scat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/533922/5001).)
- reduce the value of the `\medmuskip` parameter (default value: 4mu), which governs the amount of whitespace inserted around binary operators such as `+` and `-`.

Nine of the 14 columns in the array contain binary-op `+` and `-` symbols. As the following screenshot demonstrates, reducing the value of `\medmuskip` from `4mu` to `1mu` allows raising the value of `\arraycolsep` from `1.25pt` back to `2.5pt`. In consequence, the intercolumn space now exceeds the space around the `+` and `-` symbols. In my opinion, this makes for a more visually balanced and hence also more readable result.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{14} % default: 10
\begin{document}

\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{1.25pt} % default: 5pt
\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \ldots & \frac{n}{2}-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+1 & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots & n-3 & n-2 & n-1 & n  \\
1 & \frac{n}{2}+1 & 3 & \frac{n}{2}+3 & \ldots & \frac{n}{2}-1 & n-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots & 4 & n-2 & 2 & n  \\
\end{pmatrix}.
\]

\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{2.5pt} % default: 5pt
\setlength\medmuskip{1mu}     % default: 4mu
\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \dots & \frac{n}{2}-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+1 & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \dots & n-3 & n-2 & n-1 & n  \\
1 & \frac{n}{2}+1 & 3 & \frac{n}{2}+3 & \dots & \frac{n}{2}-1 & n-1 & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \dots & 4 & n-2 & 2 & n  \\
\end{pmatrix}.
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can split the object across two lines:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\sigma=\biggl(
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  & \begin{array}{@{}*{7}{c}@{}}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \dots & \frac{n}{2}-1 & \frac{n}{2} \\
    1 & \frac{n}{2}+1 & 3 & \frac{n}{2}+3 & \dots & \frac{n}{2}-1 & n-1
    \end{array}
  \\
  & \begin{array}{@{}*{7}{c}@{}}
    \frac{n}{2}+1 & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots{} & n-3 & n-2 & n-1 & n \\
    \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots{} & 4 & n-2 & 2 & n
    \end{array}\biggr).
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\sigma=\biggl(
  \begin{array}{@{}*{7}{c}@{}}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \dots & \frac{n}{2}-1 & \frac{n}{2} \\
  1 & \frac{n}{2}+1 & 3 & \frac{n}{2}+3 & \dots & \frac{n}{2}-1 & n-1
  \end{array}
\\
  \begin{array}{@{}*{7}{c}@{}}
  \frac{n}{2}+1 & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots{} & n-3 & n-2 & n-1 & n \\
  \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n}{2}+2 & \ldots{} & 4 & n-2 & 2 & n
  \end{array}\biggr).
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]